# Servlet Filter doesn't seem to work in Dropwizard

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, servlet-filters, dropwizard

I have written a filter called RequestFilter (implements Filter interface) to get HTTP headers of each request. And I added this filter using the following code in Dropwizard run function.

```
environment.servlets().addFilter("RequestFilter", new RequestFilter());
```

doFilter doesn't get called on sending a request.

Any hints on why it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this issue by adding the following in dropwizard run function.

```
environment.servlets().addFilter("RequestFilter", new RequestFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), true, "<resource_path>/*");
```